# Keep placeholder of Input CSS only

Tags: css

I have an `input` field with a `placeholder`. On `focus` of it, I need a `transition` of `placeholder` and it **should stay** at a different position.

I *cannot* modify the HTML as it's getting generated from a plugin.

I have achieved the transition, but the placeholder disappears after it.

Need it by **CSS-only**.

[**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NiLC9Pa8vNtiUwLzprXQ?p=preview)

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

input {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease, font-size 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease, font-size 0.3s ease;
}

input:hover::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease, font-size 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease, font-size 0.3s ease;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-40px);
  transform: translateY(-40px);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease, font-size 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 12px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease, font-size 0.4s ease;
}
```

```html
<h3>Todo: Make placeholder persistent</h3>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="This placeholder should stay" />
</div>
```

Comment: Could you add your code to the question as a code snippet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since we cannot change the HTML we will have to use a pseudo-element...and a new pseudo-class to target the `.container` when the input receives `:focus`

[**:focus-within**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)

> The `:focus-within` CSS pseudo-class represents an element that has received focus or contains an element that has received focus. In other words, it represents an element that is itself matched by the `:focus` pseudo-class or has a descendant that is matched by `:focus`

```css
.container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  position: relative;
}

.container::before {
  content: "This placeholder should stay";
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: grey;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

.container:focus-within::before {
  font-size: 12px;
  top: -100%;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

input {
  width: 500px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 0
}
```

```html
<h3>Todo: Make placeholder persistent</h3>
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" placeholder="This placeholder should stay" />
</div>
```

Comment: nice one. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to achieve this effect with the inputs `<label>`. You can't achieve it with a placeholder as this is how placeholders work, you can't not hide them when there is focus.

If you `position: absolute` the `<label>` over the input then you can `transform: translateY()` it to achieve the same effect you have there.

**Edit**: To add this should provide you slightly better UX and accessibility by doing this with a label instead of relying on the placeholder as well.

This is also a very simple version of what you want to achieve: http://plnkr.co/edit/WCdSajNRyM4mj4GBXCHh?p=preview